# how to decrypt one way hash password from asp membership table?

Tags: asp.net

In my website I have used asp.net login controls for my login module but the problem what I am facing is when I trying to fetch password the asp membership table provides encrypted value 
but I want to decrypt,how its possible.

any body help me regarding which algorithm they used,is there any stored procedure are functions for encrypting the value ,how to decrypt?

Comment: the term 'one way' should give you a hint...

Comment: You don't fetch passwords.  You fetch the hashed password, hash the supplied password, and compare the hashes.  There's no valid reason why you would ever need to be able to read a user's password.

Answer (score 1):

You dont ever decrypt them thats the point of a one way encryption algorithm.

Instead encrypt the password you were given and compare that to the stored one when you are authenticating new users.